# Confusion about Timing Measurements

Tags: c

I have been tasked with implementing three different functions get_current_time_seconds1, 2 and 3, and then have to estimate the resolution of the various functions. How would I estimate this?

Which timing function would you suggest to use? What do the compiler options -O0 -lrt mean when I have to compile with gcc -O0 -lrt timing.c -o timing?

```
#define BILLION 1000000000L

#define LIMIT_I 1000
#define LIMIT_J 1000

double get_current_time_seconds1()
{
    /* Get current time using gettimeofday */
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    printf("%s\n", asctime(tm));
    return (double) tm;
}

double get_current_time_seconds2()
{
    struct timespec start,stop;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
    double x = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);

    printf("%lf\n", x);

    return (double) x;
}

double get_current_time_seconds3()
{
    uint64_t diff;

    struct timespec start, end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    sleep(5);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("elapsed time = %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int)diff);

    return (double) diff;
}
```

Comment: You can estimate their resolution by calling them all in one loop and printing all their results when any one result has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I estimate this? Which timing function would you suggest to use?

If you want to get the resolution (precision) of the various timing elements, you can use the [`clock_getres`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_getres) function, passing in the various `CLOCK_` id types, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void printres(clockid_t id)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    int rc = clock_getres(id, &ts);
    printf("clock id: %d\n", (unsigned int)id);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("Error: %d\n", rc);
        return;
    }
    printf("tv_sec = %lu\ntv_nsec = %lu\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printres(CLOCK_REALTIME);
    printres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    printres(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID);
    printres(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID);
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, `tv_nsec` for all but `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is `1000`, for `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` the value for `tv_nsec` is `1`, this means that the precision for the other clock types is 1 millisecond (1000 nanoseconds) while the precision of `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is 1 nanosecond.

For your first function that calls [`localtime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) the precision for that would be 1 second as that function calculates the time from the Unix epoch in seconds.

> What do the compiler options -O0 -lrt mean when I have to compile with gcc -O0 -lrt timing.c -o timing?

For some compilers like `gcc` and `clang` the option `-O` means to optimize the code when compiling it to the level specified, so `-O0` means *not* to optimize the code at all, this is usually useful when debugging code.

The `-l` option says to compile against the specified library, so `-lrt` says to compile using the `rt` library, or "real time library"; this is necessary on some systems as `CLOCK_REALTIME` can be defined in that library.

I hope that can help.